# Asp.net core webapi getting null value posted from Angular11 app. Api works in postman

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core

asp.net core gets null values from angular reactive forms. tried passing the formdata without and with json stringify.
newbie in angular and trying to make a crud operation
My class definition in the API

```
     public class KitchenType
        {
            public int KitchenTypeid { get; set; }
            public string KithcenTypeDescription { get; set; }
              [DefaultValue("1")]
            public string IsActive { get; set; }
            [DefaultValue("0")]
            public string IsDelete { get; set; }
            //public DateTime Createon { get; set; }
            //public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Kitchen> Kitchens { get; set; }
        }
     
   
    angular component.ts
     
     ngOnInit(): void {
        this.Kitchentypeform=this.fb.group(
          {
    
            KitchenTypeDescription:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
    
          }
        )
    
    OnSubmit()
      {
        if (this.Kitchentypeform.invalid) {
          return;
    }
    else
    {
      this.formData = this.Kitchentypeform.value;
      var jsondata = JSON.stringify(this.formData);
      console.log(this.formData);
     return this.service.addKitchenType(jsondata).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    this.data = data
    
     });
```

[CONTROLLER CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9RgI.png)
certain values of the class are set to default and i am trying to capture only kitchentype desc from the angular form .

Comment: Could you provide `addKitchenType(...)` method please ? Maybe there is a mistake with your param

Comment: ```addKitchenType(formdata)
{
  console.log("in service--");
  console.log("service"+formdata);
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
 
  let bodystring=JSON.stringify(formdata);
  
 
 return  this.http.post(this.APIUrl+'/KitchenType/post/AddKitchenType',bodystring,{headers});
  
}```

Comment: problem resolved. there was a spelling mistake in the kitchentype description .